# how to extract xml data within csv entry

Tags: xml, scala, csv, apache-spark

I need to load the data to the spark dataframe which is having some XML and text content. Below is my data format.

```
1,2003,4349,<c><ab a="Roy" b="201"/><ab a="Joe" b="202"/></c>,54,M
```

I need to get the final output as below.

```
+--------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------+---------+
|   Month|Year          | pincode            |        name |      id      |  manager_name|manager_id   |dep_id |Gender   |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+
|1       |2003          |4348                |      Roy    |   201        |Joe           | 202         |    54 |M        |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using spark-xml library yet?

Comment: I tried using spark-xml since it is nested XML, I am not getting how to get the output

Comment: Well, you'll need to initially use the regular csv reader, but can you share the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  can get the desired result using [spark-xml library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml).

```
  import com.databricks.spark.xml._
  import com.databricks.spark.xml.functions.from_xml

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val df = // Read csv file
  
  // Assuming your xml content column name is xmldata
  val xmlSchema = schema_of_xml(df.select("xmldata").as[String])

  df.withColumn("xmldata", from_xml('xmldata, xmlSchema))
    .select("*", "xmldata.ab")
    .selectExpr(df.columns.diff(Array("xmldata")) ++
      Array("ab[0]._a as name", "ab[0]._b as id", "ab[1]._a as manager_name", "ab[1]._b as manager_id"): _*)
    .show(false)
/*
+-----+----+-------+------+------+----+---+------------+----------+
|Month|Year|pincode|dep_id|Gender|name|id |manager_name|manager_id|
+-----+----+-------+------+------+----+---+------------+----------+
|1    |2003|4349   |54    |M     |Roy |201|Joe         |202       |
+-----+----+-------+------+------+----+---+------------+----------+ /*
```